After signing a message, how to verify the signature with JavaScript/TypeScript?
At the frontend, user signs an arbitrary message (e.g., "Sign this message to prove that you own this wallet"). We can do this via, for example, UniSat's signMessage function (see here).
I want to verify this message at the backend. I want something like this:
function verifySignature(message: string, address: string, signature: string): boolean

How to achieve this? Note that it's address instead of publicKey that is in the function parameter list.
I know Bitcoin wallet Apps or browser extensions use ECDSA to sign a message (or more precisely, the SHA256 digest of the message), but the signing processes differ among various types of Bitcoin address (P2PKH, P2SH, P2WPKH, P2WSH, P2TR). So I want some JavaScript/TypeScript packages that can do this robustly instead of implementing on my own.

bitcoin-sdk-js supports signing & verification for p2pkh, p2wpkh and p2tr with an address parameter.
import * as bitcoin from 'bitcoin-sdk-js'

assert.strictEqual(
  await bitcoin.crypto.verifyMessage(message, signature, address),
  true,
);

Note that segwit address(p2wpkh, p2tr) should follow BIP322 signing schema. However, it's not widely adopted yet, so I'm not sure if the signature generated from UniSat does follow BIP322.
Disclaimer: I'm the owner of the library.

The example in the documentation of signMessage has a line that shows a verifyMessage function.

According to the example the parameters appear to be:
verifyMessage(pubkey, message, signature)
Unfortunately, the function does not appear to be documented in the same GitBook. You could attempt using the function as it is used in the example, and/or try to contact UniSat to request that they document the function.
